# Wrap All Routes with *ngIf Angular 2

Tags: angular, routes

I have an application with the following routes

```ts
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Layout } from './layout.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './../authentication/authentication.guard'
import { AuthorizationGuard } from './../authentication/authorization.guard'

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: Layout, children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'pricingreview', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'pricingreview', canActivate: [AuthorizationGuard], data: { area: 'Pricing Review' }, loadChildren: () => System.import('../pricingreview/pricingreview.module') },
        { path: 'storelists', canActivate: [AuthorizationGuard], data: { area: 'Store Lists' }, loadChildren: () => System.import('../storelists/storelists.module') },
        { path: 'authorizations', canActivate: [AuthorizationGuard], data: { area: 'Authorizations' }, loadChildren: () => System.import('../authorizations/authorizations.module') },
        { path: 'funding', canActivate: [AuthorizationGuard], data: { area: 'Funding' }, loadChildren: () => System.import('../funding/funding.module') },
        { path: 'myhistory', canActivate: [AuthorizationGuard], data: { area: 'My History' }, loadChildren: () => System.import('../myhistory/myhistory.module') },
        { path: 'allhistory', canActivate: [AuthorizationGuard], data: { area: 'All History' }, loadChildren: () => System.import('../allhistory/allhistory.module') },
        { path: 'analytics', canActivate: [AuthorizationGuard], data: { area: 'Analytics' }, loadChildren: () => System.import('../analytics/analytics.module') },
        { path: 'users/:department', canActivate: [AuthorizationGuard], data: { area: 'User Management' }, loadChildren: () => System.import('../users/users.module') },
        { path: 'callpoints', canActivate: [AuthorizationGuard], data: { area: 'CallPoint Management' }, loadChildren: () => System.import('../callpoints/callpoints.module') },
        { path: 'products', canActivate: [AuthorizationGuard], data: { area: 'Product Management' }, loadChildren: () => System.import('../products/products.module') },
        { path: 'pricingmanagement', canActivate: [AuthorizationGuard], data: { area: 'Pricing Management' }, loadChildren: () => System.import('../pricingmanagement/pricingmanagement.module') },
    ]
  }
];

export const ROUTES = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

All these routes are wrapped with a Guard that prevents access to the route itself. I have a service that is polled occassionally to get access information so a user can be on a route and lose access. I want to add an *ngIf wrapper to the template of the route like so

```ts
<div *ngIf="ctx.userInRole([route.data.value.area])">
       I have Access
</div>
<div *ngIf="!ctx.canEdit(route.data.value.area)">
       You No Longer Have Access to this Area
</div>
```

Is there a way to add a similar wrapper to every route without doing this? I am guessing I need a directive that you can pass a template into?

Answer (score 0):

You can for example create a wrapper component

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'access-wrapper',
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="ctx.userInRole([route.data.value.area]) | async">
       <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!ctx.canEdit(route.data.value.area) | async">
       You No Longer Have Access to this Area
    </div>
})
class AccessWrapperComponent { 
  constructor(public ctx:AccessService, public route:ActivatedRoute) {}
}
```

and use it like

```ts
<!-- template of the component added by the router>
<access-wrapper>
  <div> this is the visible content of the component</div>
</access-wrapper>
```

The visible content is transcluded when `ctx.userInRole()` returns true.

I used the `| async` pipe, because  you should avoid polling. The service should instead provide an `Observable` components can subscribe to an get notified when a change happened.
See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service